# When is aliasing required when using SQL set theory clauses?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I just started learning SQL and am trying to learn from my mistakes. In one of my practice exercises, I had to find city `name`s from the `cities` database are not listed as `capital` cities in `countries` database. Initially I tried the code below but it yielded an error.

```
SELECT name
FROM cities 
EXCEPT
SELECT capital
FROM countries
ORDER BY capital ASC;
```

The correct code is:

```
SELECT city.name
FROM cities AS city
EXCEPT
SELECT country.capital
FROM countries AS country
ORDER BY name;
```

Can someone explain to me why aliasing made all the difference here?

Comment: The EXCEPT result-set has column names from its first SELECT. Column aliases aren't required here, simply do `ORDER BY name ASC`.

Comment: Haven't tested this, but I don't think it's your alias that makes the difference, more the change in your order by from capital to name which did it, as the order by runs on the result of the entire operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ORDER BY` for a UNION, EXCEPT or INTERSECT sorts the complete result. The column names of the overall query are defined by the first query. So this query:

```
SELECT name
FROM cities 
EXCEPT
SELECT capital
FROM countries
```

returns a result with a single column named `name`.

Adding an `order by` is conceptually the same as:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT name
  FROM cities 
  EXCEPT
  SELECT capital
  FROM countries
) x 
order by ....;
```

As the inner query only returns a single column `name`, that's the only column you can use in the `order by`.

The aliases that you used in your second query don't change the column name of the overall result which determines the column names available for the `order by` clause.

Comment: To minimize confusion, I would recommend that you always use the same aliases for the same columns in both branches of the `UNION`.